# How to access environment variable in web.xml

Tags: java, environment-variables, web.xml

How can i set the context param-value with an environment variable in web.xml?

I tried to do it like below, but it didn't work

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>testName</param-name>
  <param-value>${TEST_HOME}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Where $TEST_HOME will be an environment variable.

is there any way to put external variables in web.xml ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing Environment Variables in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404384/referencing-environment-variables-in-web-xml)

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>Name</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>value</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but is it possible to use the OS environment varibales directly in web.xml?

Comment: Wrong answer, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404384/referencing-environment-variables-in-web-xml instead