# Can I use Java System Property in hadoop's configuration xml?

Tags: java, xml, hadoop

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404384/referencing-environment-variables-in-web-xml), I can use Java System Property in tomcat's conf xml. Does this also apply to hadoop's configuration file, like `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. e.g.

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>${user.home}/hadoop-1.2.1/hdfs/name</value>
</property>
```