# Java runtime parameter in web.xml

Tags: java, servlets

Is there a way to reference a Java runtime parameter (e.g. `-Dfoo=bar`) in a servlet container's `web.xml`? E.g., in a `Spring` context config, I can do `systemProperties['foo']}`. Can I do something similar in web.xml?

In case you're curious, I am trying to parameterize the security level:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:context*.xml
        classpath*:security-${sec.level}.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

So that either security-**high**.xml or security-**low**.xml can be used depending on the parameter set when launching the server's java command. I'm currently do resource filtering in Maven when I build my war but that makes a war with a fixed security setting. I would like it to be contingent on the runtime environment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404384/referencing-environment-variables-in-web-xml